# deja dup backup will not launch

Tags: 11.10, backup

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with deja-dup (22.0~bzr1290.37~oneiric1 and duplicity 0.6.15-0ubuntu2.  My problem is it is no longer running any backups.  It just "quit".  If i goto the unity dash and click on the icon, nothing happens.  I have un-installed both, re-booted, re-installed, re-booted and still nothing is happening.  Anyone have any idea as to what has happened, and/or what can I do to get it back to working order.  It WAS working, and doing incremental backups on a set schedule.  But no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deja-dup-team/+archive/testing), a version of a package that was not tested by official ubuntu maintainers:

> This PPA holds development releases of Déjà Dup. If you want to live
>   on the bleeding edge or to help test development versions, please
>   enable this PPA and report bugs!

Try installing the version that is in the [official ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=deja-dup):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deja-dup=20.1-0ubuntu0.2
```

- If this fixes it, remove the PPA from your software repositories.
- If it doesn't, you probably have to delete your configuration files (in home, I can't remember which files at the moment) and re-create them (because you downgraded from a newer version that might've updated existing configuration files).

If you are interested in contributing and debugging the program, try

```
DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup
```

..and file a bug report to deja-dup's website: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+filebug

Comment: I un-installed deja-dup 22.0 and re-installed in its place 20.1.  Re-booted, launched the deja-dup backup icon and still nothing.  I went to ~/.cache/deja-dup and deleted the files.  re-booted, still nothing.  You clikc the icon and nothing happens.  I don't know what config files to re-create.  What is my next step, and thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: (1) Run `deja-dup-preferences` - if it opens, try set the backup preferences as you want them to be. Click "Backup up now". (2) If it doesn't open, try running: `deja-dup --backup` - maybe it pops up an error? (3) If you don't get an error that makes sense, try this: `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup`

Comment: Actually, just do #1 and paste the output, either here or at http://www.pastebin.com and mention the link to the pastebin

Comment: deja-dup-preferences: error while loading shared libraries: libunity.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you removed any packages unity/ubuntu desktop related packages? Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal libunity6; apt-cache policy libunity6` - Currently, the latest installed libunity6 package should be version "4.0.6-0ubuntu3". If you use any other PPAs, I suggest you remove them as well.

Comment: Well, unfortunately my system puked on itself and i was forced to reload the whole system.  So, (1) I don't know what I did wrong, (2) it's all a moot point now.  Thanks for your help, I guess I created my own problem, just not sure what it is I did, but boy I did it.  Thanks Again

Comment: If you were using ubuntu 11.10 without any important packages missing, then the command above ought to be harmless. I'm sorry to hear about your situation. Note: never, ever, EVER remove ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-standard and ubuntu-minimal packages. Do not apply package changes that remove these packages.